# Json object return from YouTube for duplicated fields

Tags: c#, json, youtube, youtube-api, windows-store-apps

I have the following C# code for Json taken from YouTube Link, which has two properties with same name i.e author, author2 and inside author - name, uri (Which I changed to Uris Since it is a Keyword) On call the url it returns everything but not author, It shows null for author, help me fixing this

Here is my source code,

```
[DataContract]   
public class Title
{
    [DataMember (Name="$t")]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Name2
{
    [DataMember(Name = "$t")]
    public string authorname { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Uri2
{
    [DataMember(Name = "$t")]
    public string channelurl { get; set; }
}

public class Author2
{
    public Name2 name { get; set; }
    public Uri2 uri { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class YtChannelId
{
    [DataMember (Name="$t")]
    public string channelid { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class MediaThumbnail
{
    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    public string imgurl { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class MediaGroup
{
    [DataMember (Name="media$thumbnail")]
    public List<MediaThumbnail> media_thumbnail { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class FeAEntry
{
    public List<Author2> author { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name="yt$channelId")]
    public YtChannelId channelId { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
    [DataMember (Name="media$group")]
    public MediaGroup media_group { get; set; }
}

public class FeAFeed
{
    public List<FeAEntry> entry { get; set; }
}
    public class Name
{
        [DataMember (Name="$t")]
    public string t { get; set; }
}

public class Uris
{
    [DataMember (Name="$t")]
    public string t { get; set; }
}
public class Author
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Uris uri { get; set; }
}
public class FeARootObject
{
    public FeAFeed feed { get; set; }
    public List<Author> author { get; set; }
}
```

Regards,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the [DataMember] attribute to the author property. Only DataMembers are serialized by WCF.

Your Author2 class is also missing the [DataContract] attribute.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Could you please mark this response as the correct answer? Thx.